# ¿Como puedo hacer la secuencia 1-2+3-4-5+6...n en pseint o c++?

Tags: c++

se me solicito que debía realizar la secuencia 1-2+3-4+5-6...n, en el programa se debe solicitar la cantidad de veces a continuar con la secuencia, es decir, si de entrada se tiene 3, la salida deberá ser: 1-2+3, es decir, en los números impares se suma y en los pares se resta, sin embargo no he encontrado la manera de realizar el proceso. Seria de gran ayuda si me pudieran ayudar a encontrar la manera de realizar esto en pseint o en c++.
Anexo imagen con el procedimiento mas detalladamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba empezando a programar y no tenia claro como realizarlo, llevaba el siguiente codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int n;
    cout << "Ingresa un numero:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    if(n==1){
        cout<<n<<endl;
    else{
        for(int i = 0 ; i <=  n; i ++){
            i%2 == 0)
            sum -= i;
            cout << sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con bucles y te recomiendo que pongas las etiquetas correspondientes, si no necesitas hacerlo en python no lo pongas

Comment: function f(n){return n%2?Math.round(n/2):-Math.round(n/2); }

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque parece no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/).

Comment: Pido disculpas si no añadi el codigo, no tenia idea que era necesario, ya pude revisar y añadi la informacion que tenia, gracias.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es emplear un for y dentro del for varios condicionales, este codigo resuelve tu problema

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int sumFinal= 0;
    int n;
    cout << "Ingresa el tamaño que deseas realizar la operacion" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <  n; i ++){
        if(i%2 == 0){
            sumFinal += i;
        }else{
            sumFinal -= i;
        }
    }
    cout << sumFinal;
  
}
```

Te explicare el código, pedimos el dato n, hasta donde realizaremos la suma, ahora utilizaremos un for, inicializamos nuestro iterador en 0 y se ejecutara hasta que sea menor que nuestro tamaño que elegimos, y dentro ponemos condicionales, la condición i%2 == 0 verifica si es un numero par, ya que la operación modulo nos devuelve el residuo de una división así que en ese casi aremos la operación correspondiente, y de caso contrario que no sea par aplicamos la condición correspondiente, cada una de estas sumas se va almacenando en la variable sumFinal y al final la imprimimos
Espero te sea de ayuda, analiza el código y entiéndelo antes de copiarlo o implementarlo
Saludos

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, lo tendré en cuenta en mis próximas respuestas, solo tome en cuenta que al necesitarlo en pseint esta aprendiendo y considero que al comienzo cuando aprendemos a programar ver la solución hace que podamos entender mejor la lógica que se sigue, por eso mi comentario final que entienda primero el código, Un saludo y Gracias

Comment: La respuesta es incorrecta. Tu programa genera la serie: `0 - 1 + 2 - 3 ... (n-1)` y la serie que se necesita para el programa de OP es: `1 -  2 + 3 - 4 ... n`.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad me sirvió mucho, como decía pablo funciona, inversamente, solo es cambiarle los signos y ya, la verdad estoy empezando a programar en c++ y no sabia muy bien como ejecutar bien el codigo, de nuevo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Tome en cuenta eso, por eso el cambio de signo, si pruebas el codigo veras que te da el mismo resultado, si haces la suma hasta 6 la respuesta dara -3 y es lo mismo que devuelve el codigo

Comment: Mira que lo dudo. Tu secuencia es -1+2-3+4 y la pedida es 1-2+3-4 ... no me creo que el resultado sea el mismo. Los resultados obtenidos son 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1 ...

Comment: Entre creer y comprobar, mejor comprobar, puedes ejecutar el codigo y realizar a mano la secuencia